# Where am I going wring with the following Python code on sage math?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, python, sagemath

I am trying to solve the following system of equations but am not sure where I am going wrong with my code. I am new to writing in this language and am not sure why in my output I am getting "ilt" (not sure what this means) as well as where the g's in the output came from. I have used this exact code with a different system of functions and have gotten answers that are normal. Is there something wrong with how I put the code in or am I just not reading the output properly?

My code is: (Used on Sage math)

```
t = var('t') 
y = function('y')(t) 
x = function('x')(t) 
z = function('z')(t)

de1 = diff(x, t) == ((38/100)-(20/1800))*x + (1088/87500)*y + 0*z + 49.3
de2 = diff(y, t) == (20/1800)*x + ((-1088/87500)-(1/100)-(353/21875))*y + (7/200000)*z
de3 = diff(z, t) == 0*x + (1/100)*y - (7/200000)*z

desolve_system([de1, de2, de3], vars = [x, y, z], ics = [0, 0, 0, 0])
```

This gives the following output:

```
[x(t) == ilt(13865625/21022*(39375000000*g3242^2 + 1710528125*g3242 + 1950039)/(196875000000*g3242^3 - 65024359375*g3242^2 - 2830795000*g3242 - 73577), g3242, t) - 2773125/21022,
 y(t) == ilt(1348046875/42044*(315000000*g3242^2 - 104038975*g3242 - 1165752)/(196875000000*g3242^3 - 65024359375*g3242^2 - 2830795000*g3242 - 73577), g3242, t) - 2156875/42044,
 z(t) == ilt(96289062500/10511*(315000000*g3242^2 - 104038975*g3242 - 4529272)/(196875000000*g3242^3 - 65024359375*g3242^2 - 2830795000*g3242 - 73577), g3242, t) - 154062500/10511]
```

Comment: In this case it appears that "Python" code was actually run using Sagemath and not Python, as demonstrated by using [SaceCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/).  The code in Sagemath uses a Maxima process to calculate the desired values. The "gxxxx" result is due to an improper interpretation of the Maxima result.

Comment: `ilt` stands for "Inverse Laplace Transform".

Comment: This is not a programming website. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just interpreting what I see.

Your solution requires the eigenvalues of the system matrix, the roots of a cubic polynomial. `g3242` is the generator of a 6-dimensional algebra over the rationals that contains all the roots. One could reduce the rational functions, which probably are the exponent factors of the solution basis exponentials, to polynomials of degree 5, but the cost would be much larger coefficients.

`ilt` and `g3242` are internals of the underlying CAS system that should be resolved on the front-end. Do you use the most recent version of all the software in this bundle?